# Update property modelview from another modelview

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

For example I'm have settingsmodelview with 2 properties Path and Directory. And I have another modelview

```
Class ExpModelView
{
    SettingsModelView settings;
    ...
}
```

How I can change data in ExpModelView, when changing Path in settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use dependency injection to to inject `ExpModelView` into `SettingsModelView` and then inside the `Path` property's setter, update `ExpModelView`.
2. Use dependency injection to inject the `SettingsModelView` into `ExpModelView` and subscribe to an invent that is inside `SettingsModelView` that raises an event when the `Path` settings change.